# Little trouble with css

Tags: css

Hello i have some issues with my code because animation won't work here's my code:

```
  background-image:url(industry2.jpg); 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  border:1px solid red;
  -webkit-animation: fadein 2s ease-in ;
  -moz-animation: fadein 2s ease-in ;
  animation: fadein 2s ease-in ;
  width:500px;
  height:200px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left top;
  padding-top:68px;
  position:absolute;
  top:2700px;
  left:1300px; 

@keyframes fadein {
from { opacity: 0; }
to { opacity: 1; }
```

you see i don't get animation working and i don't know what to do...

Comment: Please Post what is not working. Show us whats animation you are getting and what your expecting

Comment: By default, the animation plays just once (`animation-iteration-count` is `1`). Since your element has `top:2700px`, probably the animation ends to the moment you scroll the page to that element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had not closed the `@keyframes`. I have removed the left and top position for visibility purpose.

```css
.container {
  background-image: url("http://via.placeholder.com/500x200");
  background-size: cover;
  border: 1px solid red;
  animation: fadein 2s ease-in;
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left top;
  padding-top: 68px;
  position: absolute;
}

@keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">Hello</div>
```

Comment: "You had not closed the @keyframes" — They have. The question was just badly formatted so the `}` appears on the line **below** the code block formatting.